# Can I get the JSON response from a Flask-api that runs locally using URLLIB or REQUETS?

Tags: flask, python-requests, urllib2, urllib

Is there a way to save the response of a flask api that is running locally on my machine?

It may not make a great sense as I have the logic locally and there is no need to get the response again from the local URL..but in my case, I have another webhook which runs locally which means I need to run flask and my webhook locally.

I am looking to get around this..

Answer (score 0):

You can save your response on your machine through using `pickle`. But it is not recommended, because website can change their content anytime.

```
import requests
import pickle

resp = requests.get("https://github.com")
with open("test","wb") as fd:
    pickle.dump(resp,fd)

with open("test","rb") as fd:
    resp_ = pickle.load(fd)

print(resp_.url)
```